# Django ORM: Sort by count of related action of type1 but exclude when count of related action of type2 > type1

Tags: python, sql, database, django, django-models

Let's say we have following models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    pass


class Action(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='actions')
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
```

where type = 1 or 2

I need to find top 3 Items that have **most Actions of type1** but **no more actions of type2 than type1.** (count_of_action1 > count_of_action2)

Test:

```
   #item : {type1: action_count, type2: action_count}
        1: {1: 5, 2: 2},
        2: {1: 4, 2: 2},
        3: {1: 3, 2: 2},
        4: {1: 3, 2: 1},
        5: {1: 6, 2: 7},
```

should yield [1,2,3] but not 5.

The query has to be very efficient since the number of actions and items are very large. 
The underlying db is MySQL.

Does anybody know how the above can be achieved with Django ORM?

Comment: I think you should use the `extra` method of an `queryset object`. You might as well create your own manager to 'transparently' handle the query.

Answer (score -1):

Have you take a look to the django's doc about aggregates and annotate.

Comment: Of course I know about annotate! This however is not trivially done via the annotate API or F() or the combination of the two. I do read my manual first.